# ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, pagination, resultset

I am trying to implement pagination at server side using Oracle PL/SQL stored procedure.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SEARCH_CUST_RECIPIENTS(v_cust_id IN t_recipient.r_cust_id%TYPE,
                                                   v_recipient_id IN t_recipient.recipient_id%TYPE,
                                                   v_current_page IN NUMBER,
                                                   v_records_per_page IN NUMBER,
                                                   v_result_set OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                                   v_total_records_found OUT NUMBER,
                                                   v_total_pages_no OUT NUMBER)
AS
TYPE lv_result_set_row_type IS RECORD (lrecipient_id t_recipient.recipient_id%TYPE,
                    lr_cust_id t_recipient.r_cust_id%TYPE,
                    lrecipient_name t_recipient.recipient_name%TYPE,
                    lrecipient_country t_recipient.recipient_country%TYPE,
                    lrecipient_state t_recipient.recipient_state%TYPE,
                    lrecipient_pincode t_recipient.recipient_pincode%TYPE,
                    lr_acc_number t_recipient.r_acc_number%TYPE,
                    lr_bank_name t_recipient.r_bank_name%TYPE);
lv_result_set_row lv_result_set_row_type;   
BEGIN
    OPEN v_result_set FOR
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT t_temp_table.*, ROWNUM rnum
            FROM        
            (
             SELECT t_recipient.recipient_id,
                    t_recipient.r_cust_id,
                    t_recipient.recipient_name,
                    t_recipient.recipient_country,
                    t_recipient.recipient_state,
                    t_recipient.recipient_pincode,
                    t_recipient.r_acc_number,
                    t_recipient.r_bank_name
             FROM t_recipient 
             WHERE r_cust_id=v_cust_id AND recipient_id LIKE v_recipient_id||'%' ORDER BY t_recipient.recipient_id
             ) t_temp_table
     WHERE ROWNUM <= (v_current_page)*v_records_per_page
     )
     WHERE rnum > (v_current_page-1)*v_records_per_page;

       IF v_result_set%ISOPEN THEN
        LOOP 
            FETCH v_result_set INTO lv_result_set_row;
                v_total_records_found := v_result_set%ROWCOUNT;
                v_total_pages_no := ROUND(v_total_records_found/v_records_per_page);
        END LOOP;
      END IF;
END;
```

I am not able figure out what is wrong with the result set's return type and defined record type but its giving me the below error when I try to fetch the cursor v_result_set into lv_result_set_row.

```
Connecting to the database ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA_CMS.

ORA-06504: PL/SQL: Return types of Result Set variables or query do not match

ORA-06512: at "C##SCOTT.SEARCH_CUST_RECIPIENTS", line 42

ORA-06512: at line 15

Process exited.
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm wrong, this declaration isn't correct:

```
TYPE lv_result_set_row_type IS RECORD
```

Why? Because you're doing this:

```
FETCH v_result_set INTO lv_result_set_row;
```

while `v_result_set` contains this:

```
t_temp_table.*, ROWNUM rnum
                ^^^^^^^
```

and `lv_result_set_row_type` doesn't contain anything that would accept `rnum` value.

So, if you modify it to e.g.

```
TYPE lv_result_set_row_type IS RECORD (lrecipient_id t_recipient.recipient_id%TYPE,
                    lr_cust_id t_recipient.r_cust_id%TYPE,
                    lrecipient_name t_recipient.recipient_name%TYPE,
                    lrecipient_country t_recipient.recipient_country%TYPE,
                    lrecipient_state t_recipient.recipient_state%TYPE,
                    lrecipient_pincode t_recipient.recipient_pincode%TYPE,
                    lr_acc_number t_recipient.r_acc_number%TYPE,
                    lr_bank_name t_recipient.r_bank_name%TYPE,
                    rnum number                                         --> add this
                   );
```

it should be OK.

---

But not for long! A few objections:

- you're never exiting the loop; add `EXIT WHEN v_result_set%NOTFOUND;`
- `v_total_records_found` always, for each loop iteration, contains number of rows in `v_result_set`. That's not an "error", but - what is its purpose?